# Bootstrap datepicker displayed error message on perticular date

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap date-picker in my project with start date and end date with displaying 6 month span and it is working fine but it displayed wrong date.

When I select 03/01/2017(MM/DD/YYYY) it displaying 09/01/2016(MM/DD/YYYY).

It means my start date is 03/01/2017 and end date is 09/01/2016. However, when I select 09/01/2016 as end date it works fine.

However, when I select 08/31/2017 or 08/30/2017 it's not working for 08/31/2017 and 08/30/2017.

Please guide me for displaying proper date.

Not working for particular date ex when I select 08/29/2017 it displaying 03/01/2018 as end date but it failed and when I select 08/30/2017 it displaying 03/02/2018 end date, however it failed when I select 03/02/2018 or 03/01/2018.

Comment: It might be best if you can supply this in a js fiddle or something similar. If you are lost while looking at your code, most others will be lost without looking at your code.

Comment: How to add code here

Comment: You might be interested in learning [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Solved... Thanks